mprotect failed Permission denied
I developed a Qt application with Qt 6.5 on Linux (RHEL 9 distribution).
When I execute the compiled binary, the GUI opens normally but I have nearly 20 same message in the terminal in which I launch the binary:
mprotect failed in ExecutableAllocator:makeExecutable: Permission denied

I don't know how to fix it and on forums I don't really understand what is the problem (because the GUI opens and works).
After first investigations, it seems to be related to the QML part because my main.cpp create first the C++ backend, then create the QML GUI and connect both. Without the QML part, I have no more the message. But I don't know precisely why for now.
Aonther information is when I set QV4_FORCE_INTERPRETER environement variable to 0 or 1 (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-javascript-finetuning.html), I have 5 time less messages displayed but still 6 messages displayed.
Thank you in advance for any help/advice. Best regards.

Could you share your code? Without it, it is hard to help you.

I am trying to reduce my code to a minimalist example which involve this message but it will take time because I have to compile on a machine and execute on another one, with  few hundred walking meters between the two ^^

maybe https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-122102
